# How to concatenate several lines in vim

Tags: configuration, screen, vim, kdb

I am using a the `vim-screen` plugin that enable me to write scripts , start an interpreter in the same window and send lines the the interpreter. Problem is that the interpreter do not accept statements written on several lines.

exemple:
This will work `f:{[x] y:y+1; Z:y+1; :Z; };`

But this won't

```
f:{[x] y:y+1;
    Z:y+1;
    :Z;
 };
```

How can I write a vim function that I could call to reshape the lines in order to be sent to the interpreter?

**EDIT**:
I had no success in making this function, I would like to create a function that would, from a input like this (that would be visually selected)

```
F:{[a;b;r]
//ccc1
   aaa1;
aaa2;
  //ccc2
    aaa3;
};
```

output something like this `F:{[a;b;r] aaa1; aaa2; aaa3; };`
So I created a bounty

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3983437/1831275) may help you

Comment: Can you explain why Ingo's answer doesn't work?

Comment: Well when I am trying 1) to select 4 lines in VISUAL mode and the to do 2) `:'<,'>command! -range Invoke echomsg join(getline(1,2), '')` nothing is happening, how should I call this code ?

Comment: The idea is to define that `:command` **once**, then invoke `:'<,'>Invoke`. Obviously, choose a better name for the command itself :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to actually modify the buffer, `J` / `:join` do that. If you just want to join the lines that are sent to the interpreter (but keep them split in the buffer), you can retrieve the selected lines with `getline()`, and then `join()` them. Here's an example command:

```
:command! -range Invoke echomsg join(getline(<line1>,<line2>), '')
```

#### Edit

Based on that, you can "massage" the List of lines returned by `getline()`. E.g. to ignore the commented lines:

```
:command! -range Invoke echomsg join(filter(getline(<line1>,<line2>), 'v:val !~# "^\\s*//"'), '')
```

Additionally strip leading whitespace (this becomes unwieldy in a single line; better use a function now):

```
:command! -range Invoke echomsg join(map(filter(getline(<line1>,<line2>), 'v:val !~# "^\\s*//"'), 'substitute(v:val, "^\\s\\+", " ", "g")'), '')
```

Comment: There might be 50 lines... can't I use the selection ?

Comment: You can `y`ank and then `join(@", '')` the selection as well, but that doesn't take less resources, and it clobbers the register.

Comment: `<line1>` and `<line2>` here are the boundaries of the range, not individual lines.  I think that may have confused @statquant.

Comment: Can someone give me an example of how to call this code I am a bit puzzled here

Comment: If your function `F:` starts at line 2 and ends with `};` in line 8, you call this with `:2,8Invoke`.

Comment: I've added two extended variants that gets you the result from your question's edit. (The bounty provided some motivation :-)

Comment: hey Ingo that was the purpose of it :) can't we get rid of the lines numbers so  I can call it with visually selected text ?

Comment: When you press `:` in visual mode, Vim will automatically insert `:'<,'>` for you. Complete that to `:'<,'>Invoke`, and you're done. Line numbers don't have to be numerical; marks work, too! Define `:vnoremap <F5> :Invoke<CR>`, and you have a visual mode mapping for it!

Answer (score 0):

Standard continuation character in vimscript scripts is backslash **in the beginning of the next line**. So, this

```
f:{[x] y:y+1;
  \  Z:y+1;
  \  :Z;
 \ };
```

should work.